# how to get the data from custom data tag in jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to get the data from the custom tag 'data-tabval' but I am unable to get the value of it

```
<a href="#angular_code" role="tab" id="angular_code-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="angular_code">
   <span id="val" data-tabval="{{ tp }}" class="text">{{ tp }}</span>
</a>
```

angular_code: means there is some angular code
I want the value of 'data-tabval' into jquery

I have tried many methods from morning to evening but am not getting specific results. Please if anyone can help me out

Comment: you can get the attribute value in jquery by usin `$("#val").attr('data-tabval')`.

Comment: `var value = $("#val").attr("data-tabval");`

Comment: since you are using Angularjs you can try to use a directive for this and select your attributes with `function link(scope, element, attrs)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use simply the jquery `.attr` to get the required output.

```js
console.log($("#val").attr('data-tabval'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#angular_code" role="tab" id="angular_code-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="angular_code">
   <span id="val" data-tabval="test123" class="text">test here</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but for some reason on execution of console.log($("#val").attr('data-tabval')); is showing undefined in console.

Comment: Are you talking about your code result?

Comment: <a href="#{a tp a}" role="tab" id="{a tp a}-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="{a tp a}">
<span id="val" data-tabval="{a tp a}" class="text">{a tp a}</span></a>

that's my actual code..now I that code I applied this jquery line

var val = $('#val').attr('data-tabval');
console.log(val);

so upon running this code in console log it shows me 'undefined' for 'val'

Comment: the thing is when I write the js in HTML page it's working, but when I am writing in separate JS file it's giving me undefined in console log.

Comment: Can you show how you are injecting js in your code?Or else you might need to include console.log into document Ready!

Comment: give me your email id..ill show you

Answer (score 1):

you can Gate custom Attribute value this code example:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
      alert($(this).attr("aria-controls"));
      alert($(this).attr(" data-toggle"));
});
```

And others attribute or custom attribute

Comment: its not working

Comment: please see again code I am replacing jQuery to '$' sign  You Can See This link: https://jsfiddle.net/sayed021/0502t3ts/2/  But it not matter, I hope Your Another Problem. because my code still working.

Comment: The thing is when I write the js in HTML page it's working, but when I am writing in separate JS file it's giving me undefined in console log.

Comment: please share me Your Message

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code snippet for your requirement:

```
var value = $("#val").attr("data-tabval");
```